# Issue Editing Mode by swiped cell in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, editing

I have the following problem. If I swipe the cell only until the delete button is visible and then click on edit, the table is not in editing mode but the button shows it.

[image: First]
[image: Swipe until delete is visible]
[image: Edit Button pressed]

I have already seen with the methods `shouldBeginEditingAtRow` and `didEndEditingAtRow` that if I first swipe a row until the delete button and then just swipe the next row, that the status of the `tableView.isEditing` is `true`.
That means if I swipe a row until delete button is visible and then click edit, `setEditing` will set the status of the tableView to `false`.

I have already tried to set the status to false in the `didEndEditingAtRow` method.But unfortunately this did not work. Do you have a tip or a solution for me?

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(!isEditing, animated: true)
        tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, whenever you are overriding a UIKit Method try to pass the parameters from the method you are overriding So update **setEditing** method with these lines:

```
   override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
         super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
             //handle Animation
             if editing  {
               self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: .none)
             }
         tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
 }
```

Comment: hi,

i tried your code and it works, but causes the executed animations when the table goes in and out of edit mode not to be executed smoothly. Most likely it is due to `tableView.reloadData()` in `setEditing()`. So I'm not completely satisfied with the solution yet.